# How to edit multple column names?

Tags: sed

I have a file like this:

```
CHROM POS ID A1_FREQ A1 REF DIR P OBS_CT
1 785989 1:785989:T:C 0.152651 T C + 0.152225 1641
1 1130727 1:1130727:A:C 0.0877514 C A - 0.987139 1641
1 1156131 1:1156131:T:C 0.160878 C T - 0.764454 1641
1 1158631 1:1158631:A:G 0.10847 A G + 0.795453 1641
```

and I would like to change those 9 column names to be these 9 names:

```
Chr BP Marker MAF A1 A2 Direction pValue N
```

I should mention that all my columns are space separated.

I could do this doing something like:

```
sed -e '1s/CHROM/Chr/' -e '1s/POS/BP/' ...
```

but the command would be too long...is there is another way to do this?

Comment: Hello I know that I could change the column names with sed -e '1s/CHROM/Chr/' -e '1s/POS/BP/' ... but that would be too long if I have many column names...I was wondering if there is another way to do this?

Comment: I would recommend you to always share your efforts, as you now did, even if they failed, otherwise it seems you tried nothing at all.

Comment: Where do you have the new column names? A file, a variable?

Comment: @Quasímodo It appears they actually did share what they tried to do.

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, after my first comment (now deleted).

Comment: @Quasímodo I did not spot that comment, my apologies.

Comment: @Kusalananda No problem, you could not spot it once it is deleted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'NR == 1 { $0 = "Chr BP Marker MAF A1 A2 Direction pValue N" }; 1' file >newfile
```

This would use `awk` to simply output the complete new header in place of the header in the file.  All other lines are retained as they are in the original file.  A new file called `newfile` is created with the result.

Using `sed`:

```
{
    echo 'Chr BP Marker MAF A1 A2 Direction pValue N'
    sed 1d file
} >newfile
```

This outputs the new header, then continues to produce the lines from the original file, apart from the first line. As before, the output is stored in `newfile`.

Comment: Thank you so much!